# Why do I get "variable referenced from scope but not defined" error when using ServiceStack OrmLite?

Tags: c#, ormlite-servicestack

I have an SQL Server table `Employee` with a column `EntryDate` defined as `DATETIME`.

I also have the following poco:

```
public class Employee
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public DateTime EntryDate {get; set;}
    ...
}
```

When I query the table using:

```
Db.Select<Employee>(e => e.EntryDate >= new DateTime(2014, 8, 15));
```

Or:

```
Db.Select<Employee>(q => q.Where(e => e.EntryDate >= new DateTime(2014, 8, 15)));
```

I get what I expect, **however** when I try to run:

```
Db.Select<Employee>(e => e.EntryDate.Date >= new DateTime(2014, 8, 15).Date));
```

Or:

```
Db.Select<Employee>(q => q.Where(e => e.EntryDate.Date >= new DateTime(2014, 8, 15).Date));
```

I get:

> variable 'e' of type 'Employee' referenced from scope '', but it is
>   not defined

Just to confirm, writing raw SQL also works fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: Something in my brain is ringing the == vs .equals() argument here, but I could be incorrect about that. And not literally, like the definition behind what x == y and x.equals(y) means.

Comment: @WhyCry, it's not the `.equals()` as that's the first thing I tried which gives me the same error

Comment: My guess is that Date is a property on the DateTime structure, but it doesn't exist in SQL which the ORM translates the expression to.

Comment: OrmLite's expression parser doesn't support transforming nested property access like this into server-side SQL.

Comment: I'm running into this as well. @mythz OrmLite should really give a better error message in this case. A user can waste a lot of time on this.